# function template overloading: const* vs. const&

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

When I have two templated function overloads like this:

```
template<class T>
void foo( T const& )
{
    // do something with a const reference
    cout << "const reference version";
}

template<class T>
void foo( T const* )
{
    // do something with a const pointer
    cout << "const pointer version";
}
```

Why does the compiler choose the first version when instantiated with a non-const pointer type?

```
int* bar;
foo( bar ); // prints "const reference version"

char const* baz;
foo( baz ); // prints "const pointer version"
```

Comment: You can find a nice explanation of this problem on channel 9: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-Cpp-3-of-n. But basically Mark B answered your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is because `bar` is a non-const pointer, so `int* const&` is actually a better match than `int const*` because it doesn't have to add `const` to the pointer type.

If `bar` were `const` qualified then it would be an exact match for the `T const*` version.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void foo(int const&) {
    cout << "const reference" << endl;
}

void foo(int const*) {
    cout << "const pointer" << endl;
}

int main() {
    int *hi;
    foo (hi);   //const pointer
    foo((*hi)); //const reference
    foo(&(*hi));//const pointer
}
```

The deal here is references and pointers are different.  A pointer is a unique type, where as a reference to a value is no different from the value itself, or rather, an alias to the object.  So for example, this version of the code above will not compile.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void foo(int const&) {
    cout << "const reference" << endl;
}

void foo(int) {
    cout << "hi there" << endl;
}

int main() {
    int hi;
    foo(hi); //const reference
}
```

As the declarations of foo are ambiguous.  The compiler cannot decide between them.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine what is going on with your template types using `typeid`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

template<class T> void foo( T const& ) {
    cout << "const reference version T="<< typeid(T).name()<<endl;
}

template<class T> void foo( T const* ) {
    cout << "const pointer version T="<<typeid(T).name()<<endl;
}

int main() {
    int* i_ptr=0;
    foo(i_ptr);

    const int* ci_ptr=0;
    foo(ci_ptr);    
}
```

This outputs (note exact output will depend on your compiler)

```
const reference version T=Pi
const pointer version T=i
```

Which shows that in the first case `T = int*` and the full argument type is `int* const&`, and in the second `T=int` and the full argument type is `int const *`.

Answer (score 0):

`template<class T> void foo( T const* )` requires a const pointer on `T`. Well if it was the only declaration you had, there will be a compilation error as you are trying to pass a non const pointer as argument.

With `template<class T> void foo( T const& )` the type `T` inferred is `int*` which is given by reference to the function.